# How to translate「業魔灰燼剣」"Gouma Kaijinken" to English?

Tags: video-games

How would I translate 「業魔灰燼剣」"Gouma Kaijinken"?

This is from Tales of Destiny: Director's Cut (テイルズ オブ デスティニー ディレクターズカット)

And here is a short video showing what it looks like:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nm4DSjqDK8w

I've tried Google Translate, DeepL, Microsoft Bing Translator, and looking at the characters individually, or pairing them up as 「業魔」 + 「灰燼」 + 「剣」

Some things I've come up with so far:

1. Daemon Ash Fire
2. Daemon Hellfire
3. Daemon Ash Sword
4. Devil Ash Blade

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This 業魔灰燼剣 is the name of a 技 (skill/move), not the name of a particular physical sword. In modern Japanese, 灰燼 is a rare word but it is used almost exclusively in set phrases 灰燼に帰す and 灰燼と化す. So the meaning of 業魔灰燼剣 is either "a demonic move that can reduce enemies into ashes" or "a move that can reduce even even strong demons to ashes", but not "a sword made from ashes of a devil/demon".

For this reason, I feel "Daemon Ash Sword" and "Devil Ash Blade" might be a little off. The other options may not be the literal translation, either, but I think it's up to you. (I personally feel Daemon Hellfire is the "safest", but please note that purely opinion-based questions are off-topic on this site.)